# How to call a Dictionary Object with Func as parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I'm getting this library, internally developed by a previous developer that looks like the following

```
public MyClass<T>
{
    public Dictionary<String, Func<T,String>> AttributesUsing{ get; set;}
    public void  setAttributesUsing(Action<Dictionary<String, Func<T, String>>> t)
    {
                AttributesUsing = new Dictionary<String, Func<T, String>>();
                t(AttributesUsing);

    }

}
```

In razor view, we can call the component like so

```
....
....

.setAttributesUsing(attr =>
{
    attr.Add("width", item => (item.ActualDays * 19).ToString());
});

....
```

The question is in the back-end code that he hasn't finished, how do we call it?

This is the following piece that's relevant

```
foreach(T item in DataSource)
{
      MyClass<T> m = new MyClass<T>()
      m.AttributesUsing(???????)  <---- what do i pass in here?
}
```

I tried to pass in the T object like so

```
m.AttributesUsing(item)
```

but obviously that's a no go. Getting "cannot be used like a method" as it's a Dictionary object. A bit confused.

Thanks

Comment: You provide an `Action<T>` that provides a `Dictionary<String, Func<T, String>>` where `T` is whatever was provided to the initialization of the class: `MyClass m = new MyClass()`, which I'm certain won't compile as you haven't specified `T` in that case.

Comment: I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with the term "razor view". But the syntax shown in that part looks to me like a normal C# lambda-function. Couldn't you just paste that same code into your "??????"

Comment: @Liming If `T` in your `foreach` is a dictionary of the type I mention above, then you cannot pass that alone as an argument, the method expects a delegate. Try a lambda: `m.AttributesUsing(item => item.Clear());`

Comment: Adam, you are right. Sorry, I missed the part when I post the simplified version here. Edited the original code.

Comment: Something like `m.setAttributesUsing(new Action<Dictionary<string, Func<int, string>>>(func => { /* Do something here */ }));` ?

Comment: Katana314, unfortuantely, the calling code is for external users. The library is developed to be re-usable across multiple projects. Thanks

Comment: Adam, T is not a dictionary object. Datasource is an IEnumberable<T>.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a delegate function?

something like this i suppose if im getting what you want/need.

```
public delegate string readDictionary(T obj)
{
    //do some stuff, read attributes
    //return object attributes
}
```

that way you arent passing an object (kinda) and get the returned attributes coming from it for attributesUsing()

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Figured out. Since Func returns a string, so in "MyClass", I just declared another property to "hold" the final values

```
public Dictionary<String, String> Attributes;
```

and in the calling code just loop through it and call like so

```
foreach(T item in DataSource)
{
      MyClass<T> m = new MyClass<T>()
      foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Func<T, String>> pair in m.AttributesUsing)
      { 
            m.Attributes = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            m.Attributes.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value(item));
      }
}
```

I thought there is an easier way to pass in "T" while invoking,  but looks like not.

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Servy, i meant, i thought there is a way to do it without actually looping through the Dictionary object and then invoke the func<> call on the .Value of the pair.

Comment: If you only wanted one of the values you could invoke just that one value.  If you want to do something to all of the values, you need to iterate through all of the values.  It's conceptually impossible to avoid it.  You could possibly hide it by calling a function that would do it for you (i.e. using LINQ) but that doesn't mean the iteration isn't going on under the hood.

Comment: Servy. Yeah, definitely agree! Though, if you know what LINQ method does the loop I have for m.AttributesUsing, please do let me know. Now, it's just about curiosity. THanks